# Shuffling many collections by folding over a numeric range

Tags: clojure, shuffle

Often, I find myself folding over a `range` object if I need to repeatedly transform something. This, to me though, feels like an abuse of `fold` since I never even use the numbers that I'm folding with.

Almost perfect example:

```
(ns shuffle-example
    (:import [java.util Collection Collections]))

(defn shuffle [^Collection coll rand-gen]
  (let [j-coll (java.util.ArrayList. coll)]
    (Collections/shuffle j-coll rand-gen)
    (into (empty coll) j-coll)))

(defn shuffle-many [^Collection coll n-shuffles rand-gen]
  (reduce (fn [c _] (shuffle c rand-gen))
          coll
          (range n-shuffles)))
```

1. Is this considered bad form? Is there a more idiomatic way of achieving this? I know in this case it's inefficient since it requires constant conversions between list types, but it shows my question well.
2. Is there a better way to deterministically shuffle a list in Clojure? Clojure comes with a `shuffle` function, but it doesn't accept a `Random`, so it's not very useful. Short of writing my own `shuffle` from scratch, this is the best I've been able to come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to transform a value `v` by applying a function `f` `n` times, it may be clearer to use a combination of `iterate` and `nth`:

```
(nth (iterate f v) n)
```

If you want to write a 'good' general-purpose implementation of `shuffle` that accepts a random generator, I suggest you simply adapt the [implementation in clojure.core](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/e547d35bb796051bb2cbf07bbca6ee67c5bc022f/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7149). You'll see the implementation you proposed is actually pretty close!

Regarding performance, keep in mind that if you want to shuffle a coll n times, nothing will beat the performance of repeatedly shuffling a mutable collection in place.

Comment: You're right, `iterate` + `nth` is significantly cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following to my personal library:

```clj
(defn iterate-many [coll repetitions iterate-f]
  (nth
    (iterate iterate-f coll)
    repetitions))
```

It's already proven useful. My `shuffle-many` can then be reduced to:

```clj
(defn shuffle-many [^Collection coll n-shuffles rand-gen]
  (iterate-many coll n-shuffles #(shuffle % rand-gen)))
```

As @Valentin pointed out, since my shuffle involves a conversion from/to Java collections, it's far from efficient, but it makes for a simple example.